# How to open android backup file (with .backup extension) on PC?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, backup

I created user data backup (with .backup file extension) on Philips W732 (Android 4.0.3) through service menu.
I need to open it on PC and modify (I created this backup before hard reset due to blocking by gesture key guard).
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/

Comment: Excuse me, above software dont extract  a snapshot from android OS. i have same problem. have anyone a solution?